# How to add new landing zones in addition to corp and online in Azure Enterprise Scale Landing Zone deployment ARM template?

Tags: azure, architecture, cloud

In the Microsoft documentation and reference for Azure Enterprise Scale Landing Zone architure, two type of landing zones were deployed - corp and online. corp - applications that require connectivity to on-premises, to other landing zones or to the internet via shared services provided in the hub virtual network. online - applications that will be internet-facing, where a virtual network is optional and hybrid connectivity is not required. The ARM template is also designed to create these two management groups and landing zones. In practical scenario, if we need to add multiple stages, say different landing zones for Dev, QA, Prod etc, how can it be configured?

Reference: https://github.com/Azure/Enterprise-Scale/blob/main/docs/reference/adventureworks/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Dev, QA and Prod are not different types of Landing Zones. Based on your application, they would probably all three be of the same type (either online or corp connected). You should, however, create three different landing zones (i.e. Azure Subscriptions) for each of them, in order to have proper separation of concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If available, can you please help me with any reference implementation or any architecture diagram, that can be referred to understand configuration of different environments better, in landing zones?